# Write text to a text file in RTL format

Tags: python, text-files, right-to-left

I have an array of text, I want to write it to a .txt file from right to left since it is in Arabic or Kurdish. How can I do that using python?

**Method to write to a file:**

```
with open(current_extracted_text_output_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as text_file:
    for line in extracted_lines:
        print(line)
        text_file.write(line + '\n')
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Does the MacOS text editor support rending arabic text RTL? Maybe a [right-to-left mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark) helps.

Comment: I have used PyCharm and VS Code, the problem still exists.

Comment: Your code appears correct and should be sufficient to write the file. I am not sure about PyCham, but VSCode will render Arabic script text correctly, in logical order, but isn't able to right align or wrap Arabic script text, so far from ideal for reading text files, but adequate for displaying shorter strings and for programming.